# Why zsh tries to expand * and bash does not?

Tags: bash, adb, zsh, glob, expansion

I just encountered the following error with `zsh` when trying to use logcat.
Namely, when typing:

```
adb logcat *:D
```

I get the following error in zsh

```
zsh: no matches found: *:D
```

I have to escape the `*` like :

```
adb logcat \*:D
```

While using bash, I do not get the following error.
Why would it be like this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`zsh` warns you by default if you use a glob with no matches. Bash, on the other hand, passes the unexpanded glob to the app, which is a potential problem if you don't know for certain what will match (or if you make a mistake). You can tell zsh to pass the unevaluated argument like bash with `setopt nonomatch`:

```
   NOMATCH (+3) <C> <Z>
          If a pattern for filename generation has no  matches,  print  an
          error,  instead  of  leaving  it unchanged in the argument list.
          This also applies to file expansion of an initial `~' or `='.
```

Or drop the argument instead with `setopt NULL_GLOB`:

```
   NULL_GLOB (-G)
          If a pattern for filename generation has no matches, delete  the
          pattern  from  the  argument list instead of reporting an error.
          Overrides NOMATCH.
```

Bash actually has the same option (`setopt nullglob`), and can emulate zsh with `setopt failglob`

Comment: `failglob`, not `nullglob`, I think.

Comment: ... and just turning `NOMATCH` off in `zsh` will make it work like `bash`.

Comment: @CarlNorum I actually did mean `nullglob`, but I've added `failglob` as well. And thanks for the `nomatch`, I was searching for `glob` and so it didn't come up.

Comment: setting `setopt nonomatch` in my `.zshrc` helped

Comment: There is fourth option not present in bash: `CSH_NULL_GLOB`: it is like `NOMATCH`, but fails only if all patterns fail (makes difference if there is more then one pattern). Guess `csh` has this behavior too (obvious from the option name), but I do not know how to make *bash* match this behavior.

Comment: `unsetopt nomatch` seems to have the same effect as `setopt nonomatch`, and may be more readable

Answer (score 2):

`bash` does try to expand it - it's just that when it fails to match anything, it lets the `*` through to the program you're calling.  `zsh` doesn't (at least by default).

You can make `bash` act like `zsh` by setting the `failglob` option.  Conversely, you can make `zsh` work like the `bash` default by turning off the `NOMATCH` option.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of `adb`, no need to escape with backslashes. You can try

```
adb logcat '*:I'
```

Or an environment variable

```
export ANDROID_LOG_TAGS="*:I"
adb logcat
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is: disable this by `setopt nonomatch`

(You can put it to `~/.zshrc`) For more options, see @Kevin's answer.