# Why does my zsh script works standalone but not when called by launchd?

Tags: zsh, launchd

I seeking help for to setup a periodical job on my imac with macOS Big Sur v11.4.
What I want to do, is to delete all contents of a given folder every 60 seconds with a bash or zsh script. It doesn't matter which one. Default for terminal is set to zsh. Therefore I tried it with zsh.

My current approach is to have two files. A zsh script which deletes the folder contents and for 'launchd' I have a plist which periodically should calls the script.

If I call the zsh script in terminal it works fine and deletes the folder contents.
But when it is called by launchd it returns with "no matches found" and I don't know where the problem is.

Therefore it would be very kind, if someone can help me with this.

/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.deleteGCODE.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.deleteGCODE.plist</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/deleteGCODE.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>60</integer>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/mycommand.err</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/mycommand.out</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

/usr/local/bin/deleteGCODE.sh:

```
#!/bin/zsh
dir="/Users/simon/Documents/Simplify3D/GCODE/"
rm -rf "$dir"*
```

the output of /tmp/mycommand.out:

```
/usr/local/bin/deleteGCODE.sh:3: no matches found: /Users/simon/Documents/Simplify3D/GCODE/*
```

p.s.
I am very sorry that I have postet my previous message in the wrong section.
Hopefully this time it is correct.

Comment: Are there any files in the directory when the script is run?

Comment: And if not, do you have the NOMATCH option turned on?

Comment: This has nothing to do with standalone-vs-cron, but with how `zsh` handles globs that don't match any files. You'll get the same error if you run the script manually when the directory is empty.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why zsh tries to expand \* and bash does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037364/why-zsh-tries-to-expand-and-bash-does-not)

Comment: Thanks for you'r hellp all. I didn't had turned NOMATCH on but it is now, with setopt +o nomatch. Now the error isn't visible due to that. but the files aren't deleted. The folder isn't empty.

Comment: @chepner : I think in the case of `$dir*`  (Quoting is IMO not necessary here), zsh should expand as well. At least mine does.

Comment: @Miracuru : Are you sure that you don't mean `rm -rf $dir/*` ?