# zsh/bash script fails in loop when *.css doesn't have match

Tags: zsh

I have a directory named .poco that has subdirectories at different levels.
Some have *.css files in them. Some don't. The following script fails on
line 4 (the second for loop) if the current directory has no .css files
in it. How do I keep the script running if the current directory doesn't happen to have a match to *.css?

```
#!/bin/zsh
for dir in ~/pococms/poco/.poco/*; do
    if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
    for file in $dir/*.css # Fails if directory has no .CSS files
      do
        if [ -f $file ]; then
          v "${file}"
        fi
      done
    fi
done
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why zsh tries to expand \* and bash does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037364/why-zsh-tries-to-expand-and-bash-does-not)

Comment: `for file in ~/pococms/poco/.poco/*/*.css(.):`. No need for nested loops or the `if` statement. (The proposed duplicate takes care of non-matching patterns.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because of "shell globbing". Your shell tries to replace patterns like `*.css` with the list of files. When no files match the pattern, you get the "error" that you get.

You might want to use `find`:

```
find ~/pocoms/poco/.poco -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -name '*.css'
```

and then xargs to your `program` (in that case - `echo`) like:

```
find ~/pocoms/poco/.poco\
  -mindepth 2\
  -maxdepth 2\
  -type f\
  -name '*.css'\
  -print0\
| xargs -0 -n1 -I{} echo "{}"
```

`-n1` to pass the files one by one, remove it if you want your program to accept the full list of files as args.

Comment: That did the trick.  Still trying to parse these options so I understand them thoroughly but until, I've got perfectly working c0de. Thanks you!